# Placing UIActivityIndicator in a cell when editing UITableViewCell and disable UserInteraction

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

When the user clicks on delete button in a UITableView(when editing is on) a UIActivityIndicator is shown in the middle of the tableView since i could not think of a way to put it in the middle of the Cell that is being deleted. This is the code that i am using right now:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        self.activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
        //cell.accessoryView = self.activityView;


        self.activityView.center = self.tableView.center;
        [self.tableView addSubview:self.activityView];

        [self.activityView startAnimating];
        .... rest of the code
```

So 1)

first question how to put the indicatorView in the middle of the cell that is being deleted.

2) Is there anyway to disable the delete button while this is happening? I dont want the user to massclick the button.

**EDIT1**

I forgot to mention that i am using a custom class for the cells outlets. SO in a normal tableView where you would populate i use this code to get each cell

```
GamesInfoTableViewCell *cell1 = (GamesInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:otherSection];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. It will add the subview in the center of cell you are trying to delete.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

        UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        // Setting Frame of Spinner..
        CGFloat x = (cell.frame.size.width-spinner.frame.size.width)/2;
        CGFloat y = (cell.frame.size.height-spinner.frame.size.height)/2;

        spinner.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, spinner.frame.size.width, spinner.frame.size.height);

        [cell addSubview: spinner];

        [spinner startAnimating];
        //Do YOUR WORK NOW
    }
}
```

Happy Coding..:)

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing, see the updated question. This did not work I would presume it is because of that?

Comment: I added this code to your solution [cell addSubview: self.activityView]; and the spinner appeared below the  cell close to the PickerView. I cant seem to get it to the middle of the cell. Maybe this will help you get the rest?

Comment: Which cell you want to delete? PickerView Cell or test 1-0 cell??

Comment: the test 1-0 cell. WIth your code nothing appears but when i added this to your code: [cell addSubview: self.activityView]; the spinner appears close to PickerView. I want the spinner to appear in the middle of the 1-0 cell

Comment: You are deleting cell using inbuilt swipeToDelete Feature or you have added a Delete button?

Comment: I added the built in edit button by using this code: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem

Comment: Perfect thank you. I added 70 points to the x value to compensate the indentation the cell makes when the delete button appears. Thank you

Comment: You dont have any idea how to make the delete button userinteractionenabled = NO right?, That was the second question

Comment: You can implement your own logic for that.. take a boolean and set its value to YES and put a if condition if the boolean is YES then simply return from execution block..